# shutting down takes ages (HTC Desire 2.1)

Tags: htc-desire, reboot

I wanted to reboot my HTC and it was shutting down for more than 10-15mins so I removed the battery...

What can I do next time? Is that ok to be shutting down for ever?

The mobile is almost new one. Not much stuff installed. Primarily used for web browsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has every subsequent reboot taken just as long? If so take the phone into a local store or call your carrier support line and ask them to wipe your phone so you can start out fresh. See if a fresh start helps.

Comment: I tried one more time to power off my Desire and it was never ending. So I tried to uninstall some apps and it's as quick as flash. I suspect that is was caused by 'Advanced Task Killer'

Comment: so your suggestion of wiping the phone will work...

Comment: Ah, never ever ever ever (are there enough of those?) ever use a task killer of any kind with Android 2.1 or 2.2. Both versions have a kernel that is designed to handle it's own task killing and process management. A task killer just messes that up and makes things worse.